# mysql INSERT by selecting with left join duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql, wpml

Hello I am trying to copy custom posts in wordpress with wpml 
So I have 2 tables:

1: wp_icl_translations
2: wp_posts

wp_icl_translations has rows:

```
translation_id(primary), element_type , element_id, trid, language_code, source_language_code
```

wp_posts has many rows bu I am getting only:

```
ID(primary)
```

My query:

```
Insert into `wp_icl_translations` (`element_type`,`element_id`,`trid`,`language_code`,`source_language_code` )
Select "post_timeline",`wp_posts`.`ID`,`wp_icl_translations`.`trid`,`wp_icl_translations`.`language_code`,`wp_icl_translations`.`source_language_code`
FROM `wp_icl_translations`
LEFT JOIN `wp_posts`
ON `wp_posts`.`oldid`=`wp_icl_translations`.`element_id`
WHERE `wp_icl_translations`.`element_type` = "post_news"
```

I am getting error #1062 - Duplicate entry '0-' for key 'trid_lang'
can someone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont insert a primary key (translation_id). Try `AUTO_INCREMENT` on column translation_id

Comment: translation_id is already an AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Ok then you have an unique index named trid_lang and you insert a duplicate value for this index

Comment: Thank you @sh88 for responses. 
I will try to find this index.